# Fitted an ARMAX model, now want to predict. Can/should the exogenous variables be edited in the new data points?

Tags: time-series, stata, arima, sarimax

I have fit an ARMAX (an ARMA with exogenous/independent variable) model using Stata, and would now like to use said model to predict. My do-file looks a bit like this:

```
import delimited "data.csv" 

generate n=_n
tsset n, generic

summarize 
tsline sales
dfuller sales, regress trend

arima sales holiday avg_price, ar(1)

tsappend, add(50)
```

with `sales` being the *depvar* and `holiday` and `avg_price` being the *indepvars*.

After appending 50 new empty observations for `predict`, I would like to edit the observations I have for the *indepvars*, which are stored in a csv. Is this recommended, or even possible? Should a different approach be taken?

I have tried to use `predict` without editing the exogenous variables, which predictably gave me no results. I have also only found how to edit each data point manually with the data editor.